# how to make git config respect the branch remote push setting

Tags: git, git-branch

I'm working with a forked repo, using standard naming (my fork is "origin", and upstream is "upstream").

I'd like to set up two local branches, one called "master" to track upstream/master, and another called "my-forked-master" to track origin/master.

I'd like git to remember where to push, so that when I'm on the my-forked-master branch I need only type "git push" to have git push to origin/master.

I have this in my .git/config file:

```
[branch "my-forked-master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
    push = refs/heads/master
[branch "master"]
    remote = upstream
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

But when I type "git push" in my-forked-master branch, git creates a new remote branch at origin/my-forked-master.  I've tried setting push.default to "current" and "simple" -- neither works.  Anyway, since I explicitly set my branch's remote and push settings, I thought such defaults would be irrelevant.  (They don't seem to be irrelevant though -- "simple" triggers an error about the branch names not matching).

How to I make git obey what's in .git/config and simply push to origin/master even though it doesn't match my local branch name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've tried setting push.default to "current" and "simple" -- neither works.

The correct value is `upstream`. (`simple` is `upstream` plus a check making sure the names match to prevent surprises – that won’t work here.) See [the manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-pushdefault):

> `upstream` - push the current branch back to the branch whose changes are usually integrated into the current branch (which is called `@{upstream}`). This mode only makes sense if you are pushing to the same repository you would normally pull from (i.e. central workflow).

---

> Anyway, since I explicitly set my branch's remote and push settings, I thought such defaults would be irrelevant.

Not sure that `branch.<name>.push` exists. `branch.<name>.remote` and `branch.<name>.merge` are the branch’s upstream, though, and that’s the whole point of the `push.default` setting.